# How to resolve this error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Mail_Message::__construct() must be of the type array, none given

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

My code in controller:
`

```
public function filetransport()
    {
        set_time_limit(0);       
        $message = new Zend_Mail_Message();

        $message->addTo('matthew@zend.com')
        ->addFrom('ralph.schindler@zend.com')
        ->setSubject('Greetings and Salutations!')
        ->setBody("Sorry, I'm going to be late today!");

        // Setup File transport
        $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_File();
        $transport->setOptions(array(
                'path'              => 'data/mail/',
                'callback'  => function (Zend_Mail_Transport_File $transport) {
                return 'Message_' . microtime(true) . '_' . mt_rand() . '.txt';
        },
        ));

        $transport->send($message);
    }
```

While creating instance of Zend_Mail_Message it is throwing error.The Error is

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Mail_Message::__construct()
must be of the type array, none given,
called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend-Mailer\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 102
and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend-Mailer\library\Zend\Mail\Message.php on line 57
```

If you have idea about this please let me know.....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Zend documentation](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/classes/Zend_Mail_Message.html) `Zend_Mail_Message` accepts one argument as the parameter. You are not passing any parameter. That is why you get this error.

> __construct(array $params)
>
> In addition to the parameters of Zend_Mail_Part::__construct() this
>   constructor supports:
>
> - file filename or file handle of a file with raw message content
> - flags array with flags for message, keys are ignored, use constants defined in Zend_Mail_Storage
>     Inherited_from    \Zend_Mail_Part::__construct()

From [Zend_Mail_Part docs](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Mail/Zend_Mail_Part.html#__construct),

> Zend_Mail_Part supports different sources for content. The possible
>   params are:
>
> - handler a instance of Zend_Mail_Storage_Abstract for late fetch
> - id number of message for handler
> - raw raw content with header and body as string
> - headers headers as array (name => value) or string, if a content part is found it's used as toplines
> - noToplines ignore content found after headers in param 'headers'
> - content content as string

That means, as the error is saying, you are missing the `params` array in  the constructor.